# Host address url not working for SharePoint site?

Tags: asp.net, host-header

I have created web application on port 80 in SharePoint with host address like `http://subsite.site.com`. I checked in IIS server host header was defined in the web site property. When I typed `http://subsite.site.com` on IE browser on server itself showing undefined.

How to get `http://subsite.site.com` on server and from client machine (my local machine)?

Comment: Got DNS entries set up right?

Comment: DNS entry in local server or company network server?

Comment: Either, but company network if you want it accessible across the network.

Comment: If I want access from local server (sharepoint installed server) and my local desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a Dns record set for the URL to point to the sharepoint server on your company dns server.

Eg an A host record mysite.mycompany.con points to 192.168.1.14.

Then Dns entry will send requests to your sharepoint server, and iis will pick up the host header and point to the correct web application.  Add a binding to iis and include the host header.

You also need to configure your alternate access mappings in sharepoint central admin.

Answer (score 2):

You should configure [Alternate Access Mappings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208%28office.12%29.aspx).